# What information can we obtain from a uniform, random variable?

Tags: statistics

Suppose that the time students wait for a bus can be described by a uniform random variable X, where X is between 0 minutes and 60 minutes.

a) sketch the density function

b) what is the probability someone will have to wait between 20-30 minutes?

c) what is the expected waiting time?

d) if the sd = 17.3, what are its units and what does it mean exactly?

I'm having trouble with the questions.  I don't really understand what a uniform, random variable is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The _support_ of the density function of a (continuous) uniform random variable is an interval of finite length, and the density function has constant value on that interval. The interval is usually specified (in your problem, it is $[0,60]$ and the notation $X \sim \mathcal U(0,60)$ could have been used instead) and the constant value is usually unspecified, left as an exercise for the reader to figure out. Do you know, or can you figure out, how to find the value of the density function on the interval $[0,60]$?

Comment: I don't know how to find out the values, can it just be 1?

Comment: Consider looking in the Table of Contents or the Index of your textbook for _uniform random variable_ and reading the page(s) pointed to. In the highly unlikely event that your textbook does not mention uniform random variables anywhere in the text, only in the problems, try using an Internet search engine to find on-line material, e.g. on Wikipedia, about uniform random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints to get you started:

The uniform density has constant value on its support $[0, 60]$. You know it integrates over its support to $1$. Hence, $\int_{[0, 60]} c ds = 1$ for an unknown $c$ you mean to back out from this equation, and so $c = \frac{1}{60}$. This gives you (a), and $f_X (s) = \frac{1}{60} 1_{[0, 60]}(s)$, its density ($1$ being the indicator function). To continue, use $P(X \in [20, 30]) = \int_{[20, 30]} f_X(s)$,  and $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int s f_X(s) ds$, which are easy integrals (you should get $\frac{1}{6}$, and $30$, respectively - as you'd expect). For the final part, recall that $\mathbb{V}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - {\mathbb{E}[X]}^2$, and that the standard deviation is the square root of the variance, so, using (c), you just need to calculate $\int s^2 f_X(s) ds$ and plug into the formula. It's another easy integral, and you get $17.3$ for the SD, as requested.